# Array in simple PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

Just learning bits in PHP and trying to get simple function for my nav running

```
function navigation($pages) {

            $pages = array($pages);

            if($pages) { 
                echo "<ul class=nav>";
                    foreach($pages as $id => $page) { 
                    echo "<li><a href=\"page.php?id={$id}\">";
                    echo strtoupper($page) . "</a>";
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
```

Although this function is only returning the first value

```
navigation("Home", "About us", "Contact us");
```

Is it possible to put the function values to variable? I'm not sure what I'm doing here wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
$pages = array($pages);
```

And instead call the function like this:

```
navigation( array("Home", "About us", "Contact us") );
```

Please note that you should not output HTML like this:

echo "";

But instead make sure that the CSS classname is wrapped in quotes. To achieve this, you could use escaped double-quotes:

echo "";

Or, which would be my personal preference, single quotes in the outer string and normal double quotes inside:

echo '';

Generally you can use single-quotes to define any string in PHP, with only one exception, which is when you want to put special characters in your string, such as:

- \n
- \r
- \t

and so on. These might not be interpreted correctly in a single-quoted string.

Here is a more refined version of your `navigation()` function:

```
function navigation(array $pages) {
    if(!$pages)
        return;
    echo '<ul class="nav">';
    foreach ($pages as $id => $page) {
        echo '<li><a href="page.php?id=' . $id . '">';
        echo strtoupper($page) . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SquareCat. Thank you for the PHP tip, although I cant agree on the quotes on classes. In HTML5 they are no longer requires if its a single class. I have escaped the quotes on the link. Thanks muchly for your help!

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that HTML5 speciality! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function myFunction($text){
    return md5($text);
}
$array = array(myFunction("Text to be MD5"), myFunction("More Sample Text"));
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Is this what you were looking for?
you can put the output of a function into an array
**Output:**

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
a95486400f22cfa1ce6ae3a8cacae1e4
```

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right thread? (no pun & no offense intended).